# Cannot use Bootstrap JS in Angular2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

I am using angular-cli to create a project that uses some of the bootstrap js functions like button() and modal(), but the problem is that while I am able to compile my ts file perfectly when I actually try to execute the javascript function in the browser it fails with

```
error_handler.js:53 TypeError: button.button is not a function
    at NewdeviceComponent.loading (newdevice.component.ts:122)
    at NewdeviceComponent.add (newdevice.component.ts:97)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_NewdeviceComponent0.handleEvent_67 (component.ngfactory.js:517)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.<anonymous> (view.js:408)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (dom_renderer.js:276)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:265)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:227)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:264)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:154)
    at HTMLButtonElement.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:335)
```

I am invoking the button function on after a click event like the following-:

```
button.button(loading ? 'loading' : 'reset');
```

The weird part is that VSCode gives me intelli sense and compilation actually succeeds but fails in the browser.

All the bootstrap files and styles sheets are globally loaded from the angular-cli.json.

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ]
```

Comment: How did you include Bootstrap JS in your project?

Comment: @AngularFrance In the angular-cli.json. the scripts section. Check the edit.

Comment: Sounds about right. Maybe you need to use a wrapper library like https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap?

Comment: @AngularFrance No I don't think so. If the files are loaded I should be able to use them. What's the reason I cannot use them over here ?

Answer (score 1):

Using Bootstrap's JS means that you would have to load jQuery, Bootstrap's JS and potentially create Angular wrappers around Bootstrap's JS code. But even doing so would result in rather poor integration since both jQuery and Angular would "fight" over DOM updates - the philosophy of those 2 libraries is *very* different.

In Angular context it is better to use a dedicated, native libraries that provide much better API for the Angular users. There is an excellent implementation for Angular and Bootstrap 4: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io. By using it you could skip the whole jQuery / Bootstrap JS story.

Comment: Is there wrapper for Bootstrap 3 ?

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource: What's the main difference between https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/ and https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap?

Comment: The one I've mentioned is for Bootstrap 4. This makes sense since Bootstrap 3 is not maintained any more and Bootstrap 4 is approaching Beta.

Comment: Yeah but my entire project is with bootstrap3

Comment: @AngularFrance I would argue that APIs (ease of use, flexibility) and quality of ng-bootstrap is far superior. This is mostly due to the fact that some of  ng-bootstrap members are also part of the Angular team. Another reason is strong focus on automated testing. I can reach out to you with more details if interested.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource. Thanks for your input. I'm not using either for now, but I plan to in the near future and I'll keep your answer in mind. Too bad that there isn't a single joint effort to achieve what looks like similar goals. :(